# Generic Makefile disregarding variables

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

C++ project with a directory structure and Makefile styled after this blog post [a simple c plus plus project structure](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/). However, in the modified output from running makefile the variables do not seem to carry values through the compilation process.

edited (now working): Makefile

```
HOST_COMPILER := g++
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/runner
SRCEXT := cc
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name "*.$(SRCEXT)")
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

# internal flags
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -g -fopenmp 
MAGICKFLAGS := `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags --ldflags --libs`

INCLUDES := -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 
LIBRARIES := -L/usr/local/lib/  -lMagick++-6.Q16 -lMagick++

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(HOST_COMPILER) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIBRARIES)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(HOST_COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) $(MAGICKFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)
```

In retrospect "$(" is a common pair of symbols in this code which could be reversed for the error producing "($", except makefile doesn't inform you of such a misstype. So just a search on the document for "($" would have found the error.

Comment: For c++ use `CXXFLAGS ` not `CFLAGS `

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the problem to a more simple example that readers can try.

Comment: @user3707614: I don't see output from the `@echo` commands. Do you have to enable that in some way? If so, please do so and show result.

Comment: Probably, I can reduce the size to a more readable example, I'll try that after fixing the typo of a "($" in place of a "$(".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tiny problem in your makefile! 
Substitue this:

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst ($SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
```

With this:

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
```